# Proj4 string missing datum information for SAGA outputs loaded into R

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, saga, proj

I've produced a set of topographic derivatives using both SAGA and ArcGIS. They are all in the same CRS.

When I load them into R, however, the proj4 strings are different:

```
>arcRaster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 16002, 21200, 339242400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 480200, 692200, 4896280, 5056300  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

```
> sagaRaster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 16002, 21200, 339242400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 480200, 692200, 4896280, 5056300  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Note the raster produced in saga is missing `+datum=NAD83`. They align properly and they stack without problems. Why is the datum information missing?

Comment: try to reproject data.

Comment: It doesn't need to be reprojected - I know they are in the same projection, it's just that there is an inconsistentcy in the proj4 string

Comment: For example if I open both layers in ArcMap it recognizes the projections to be the same "NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_11N". It is only when loaded into R that the projections *appear* different. Furthermore, if i simply do `crs(sagaRaster) <- crs(arcRaster)` or vis versa they still align perfectly and stack. I would expect that if they were in fact different projections, simply redefining the CRS like this would cause some offset.

Comment: check the matadata comparison `gdalinfo filename`

Comment: The datum information is there when i look with gdal info (also appear as identical coordinate system in arcmap)

Comment: ArcMap and QGIS both have different ways to read the proj4 string, you can share the data for more details. I can look into more details.